# Cloned new HDD, but get "No bootable device found" when installed

Tags: hard-drive, laptop, clone, bootable-media

I purchased a 60 Gb 1.8" drive for my Dell X1 laptop. The old drive is working find, but I wanted more storage. I cloned the old drive using xxClone and compared drives. They seem to be the same. When I install the new drive, I get the "No bootable device" error and can't even get to a dos prompt.

I cloned a spare 30 Gb drive and installed it. It functions perfectly.

I'm able to use the 60 Gb drive as a storage device using a usb cable, but it just won't function as the system drive, so I don't think it is defective.

Is there a way to get this drive to be recognized by the laptop and to be used as the system drive when installed?

Thanks

Comment: Please provide specific specifications on what you purchased so we can verify you purchase the correct hardware.

Comment: Have you tried booting with the Windows disk and see if startup repair can pick up the disk? If it does then you should be able to fix the boot sectors using the disk...

Answer (score 1):

You can download the ISO file for Partition Wizard, a free disk copy utility, and burn a boot CD (http://www.partitionwizard.com/partition-wizard-bootable-cd.html). Then boot to the CD on the laptop with the new hard drive and have a look at the disk properties to see if the partition is set to Active and not hidden. Sometimes changing the partition properties can make the hard drive bootable again.

Answer (score 0):

This usually happens when the master boot record is not cloned successfully. There's a tool to fix the mbr (comes with Hiren's Bood CD/DVD) and its called `fixmbr.exe` (commandline)

Answer (score 0):

The question doesn't specify how they compared the old and new drives so we can't know if they are really identical. Or what drives are connected when they try to boot. I would go one of these ways:

- Boot with any Live CD or Live USB (Clonezilla, Parted Magic, any kind of Windows bootable CD, Hiren's Boot CD, RIPLinux, ...) and check what partitions does that live system see, and what kind of partitions are there with e.g. `fdisk -l`. Or get information about the MBR with `cat /dev/newdisk | file -`. Also once booted you can compare the old and new disks with something like `diff /dev/olddisk /dev/newdisk`
- Boot the system with only the new cloned disk connected (sometimes one can have a data-only pendrive or disk connected and the system will fail to boot from that drive and ignore the main system drive)
- The most time consuming option: clone the disks again with a different tool, for example Clonezilla

Comment: nice answer. but a bit late to the party, no?

Comment: the system bumped the question so I guess it's still getting views